# Drawing a rounded highlight behind certain words in an EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, highlight

I need all hashtags typed inside an EditText to be highlighted by a rounded rectangle as the user is typing them. It would have to look something like this:

[image: Example]

The highlighting should update live as the user is typing words inside the EditText field. What would be a way of achieving this effect? I am fine with using libraries if any exist for this purpose.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/fenli/HashTagEditText) lib is [pretty close](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/az5qta7BY6rt1GJ1ZuHIaOxW2kVPg9510_igrcluyPBzhltUWcM=w443-h738-no) to what you need.